# Angular Directive addEventListener with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive, event-listener

I currently have a directive that adds a few event listeners to an element in the link function.

e.g.:

```
...
link: function(scope, element) {
    // this gives us the native JS object
    var el = element[0];

    el.draggable = true;

    el.addEventListener('dragstart', ...);
}
...
```

Now I use this directive inside of an `ng-repeat`.
My question is, will this make a new eventlistener for each element inside of the ng-repeat ?

If so, say I have 100 items within this ng-repeat, will this cause performance problems ?

If so, what changes could I make to attach those elements to the same event Listener ?

Comment: It depends on what `...` is.

Comment: you mean in addEventListener ?

el.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartFunction, false);

Comment: `dragStartFunction` is a reference to **one** function, so it's always the same, provided that it's not declared within the link function.

Comment: It actualy is declared in the link function, would it be better to declare it in the controller and use a reference to that in the link function ?
As controllers in directives only get loaded once.

Comment: The controller would get instantiated 100 times too, but if the function is part of the prototype, it would exist only once. Anyway, you won't have any performance problems with 100 items because of the event listeners. If that was a concern, then you would have to rethink your solution and attach one listener to a parent element (directive).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would add the event to each element in the ng-repeat. The directives are executed one time per element that have it attached.The listener itself would not cause major performance issues. (no more than the ng-repeat, that is not very performant)